# Drop Rows From Pandas Dataframe According To Date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a dataframe with pandas and drop dates later than say 201702. The dataframe is structured as so

```
    Date         Account Number
1   2019-02-21   123841234
2   2017-01-01   193741927
3   2015-03-04   981237432
4   2018-05-29   134913473
5   2012-05-12   138749173
6   2009-01-04   174917239
```

I'm reading in the csv (data.csv) and attempting to remove any date after 2017-02-28 as so:

```
data_csv = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
data_csv[data_csv.DATE < '2017-02-28']
```

Is this supposed to work correctly with a date format of YYYY-MM-DD or is there something I'd have to do to the column format to ensure that these rows are dropped from the dataframe?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your date strings are in YYYY-MM-DD format then lexicographical comparisons work out of the box (for python in general, not just pandas).

```
'2009-01-04' < '2017-02-28'  
# True

'2019-01-04' < '2017-02-28'
# False
```

So your comparison should work out without any changes. Although it'd be safer to convert to datetime first, so your code makes no assumptions while still working.

---

```
df.dtypes     

Date              object
Account Number     int64
dtype: object

df[df['Date'] < '2017-02-28']

         Date  Account Number
2  2017-01-01       193741927
3  2015-03-04       981237432
5  2012-05-12       138749173
6  2009-01-04       174917239

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')
df.dtypes

Date              datetime64[ns]
Account Number             int64
dtype: object

df[df['Date'] < '2017-02-28']

        Date  Account Number
2 2017-01-01       193741927
3 2015-03-04       981237432
5 2012-05-12       138749173
6 2009-01-04       174917239
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I believe this will work, but when I do this, my output csv is larger than my input csv. To try and explain, I'm reading a 17GB csv into a dataframe, executing the date filter as you shown above, and then to_csv that modified dataframe. But when it writes to csv, the output file is then 23GB. Is it normal for my output csv to be larger than it originally was after removing certain rows with dates < '2017-02-28'?

Comment: @JMV12 i don't think it should, unless you're doing something else that's increasing it's size?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you transform the string into a `Timestamp`, assuming `data_csv.Date` is also a `Timestamp`:

```
result = data_csv[data_csv.Date < pd.to_datetime('2017-02-28')]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
        Date  Account Number
1 2017-01-01       193741927
2 2015-03-04       981237432
4 2012-05-12       138749173
5 2009-01-04       174917239
```

Comment: You really don't, pandas is smart about string comparisons on datetime columns. Just comparing with the string directly works, assuming it follows the YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: @cs95 I guess you are right, in the sense that you don't need to, but I believe explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: Aha... quoting the zen I see... Sure, it's more a "you should" rather than a "you need to" situation :)